# SQL получить названия поля с PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Есть произвольные таблицы и необходимо узнать название поля c `PRIMARY KEY`, как это можно сделать `SQL` (использую `MySQL`) запросом или средствами `Python` v3 и библиотечки [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)?

---

Есть допустим табличка такой структуры:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `name` text,
  `this_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`this_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

И необходимо вернуть `this_id`

Comment: Какой ожидается результат, если первичный индекс является составным?

Comment: @Akina обновил вопрос, вообще столкнулся с ситуацией когда не во всех таблицах есть PRIMARY KEY и даже когда он есть он не всегда id.

Comment: Есть таблица: `CREATE TABLE test (id bigint(20) NOT NULL, val int(11) NOT NULL, txt varchar(32) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id,txt(3),val))`. Что необходимо вернуть в этом случае?

Comment: @Akina вообще массив: ['id', 'txt', 'val']. Но так подобного виде таблиц в базе нет. И вопрос решил, немного измененным решением от L.Vadim , вот запрос https://ideone.com/mWcu21

Comment: ответ помог????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного изменил [запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608826/215163) от [@L. Vadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232223/l-vadim):

```
-- Выводим значения поля COLUMN_NAME из таблице information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS pk
/*
Делаем INNER JOIN из-за того что нам нужны только пересечения полей:
  TABLE_NAME название таблицы,
  CONSTRAINT_NAME название поля с ключом 
  TABLE_SCHEMA название базы
*/
INNER JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS C ON
  C.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME AND
  C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
  C.TABLE_SCHEMA = pk.TABLE_SCHEMA

/* 
Условия:
  TABLE_NAME название таблицы,
  TABLE_SCHEMA название базы
  CONSTRAINT_TYPE поле где указан PRIMARY KEY
 */
WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME  = 'test' AND pk.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_db'
  AND pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

Вариант без комментариев:

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS pk INNER JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS C ON C.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = pk.TABLE_SCHEMA WHERE  pk.TABLE_NAME  = 'test' AND pk.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_db' AND pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

---

> Я не уверен в правельности текста ниже, так-как он был написан из быстрого изучения таблиц: `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` и `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`

Как я понял, в таблице `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` храниться информация о всех ключах для всех баз и соединяем их с таблицей `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` по полю `CONSTRAINT_NAME` где хранится название нашего ключа в нашем случаи это PRIMARY и уже в `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` находятся все поля с ключами, название поля в поле `COLUMN_NAME`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT     pk.table_name, column_name as 'primary_key'
FROM       information_schema.table_constraints pk 
INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage C 
                                    on c.table_name = pk.table_name  and
                                       c.constraint_name = pk.constraint_name
where   constraint_type = 'primary key'
           -- and pk.table_name  LIKE '%whatever%'
```

Comment: Да, код отрабатывает, у вас правда ошибочка "C" должна быть в нижнем регистре, и для некоторых таблиц возвращает  более 1 значения. вот например для такой табличке https://ideone.com/IEMKm2
P.S И да, добавил в уловие выбор базы

Comment: надо подумать как это сделать

Comment: Вообще я поправил ваш запрос, и вообще нужный результат я получаю: ideone.com/mWcu21, отличается тем что JOIN еще по полю TABLE_SCHEMA

Comment: здорово так можно сделать